# Full screen map inside drawer screen causes lag on drawer item press

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-maps

So I am currently working on a app that needs to have a drawer with multiple screens, one of them being a map. The big issue is that when i open the drawer and navigate to another screen, the experience is very laggy because the map is hard to render. What i want to do is to add some event listeners or to use some navigation props in order to render or not render the map but react-navigation eventlisteners ('didBlur', 'didFocus' etc) did not help. Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Icon } from 'native-base';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions =
        {
            drawerIcon: <Icon name="map" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} />,
            title: "Acasa"
        }
    render() {
        return (
            <MapView
                style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: 101 }}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                region={{
                    latitude: 47.141515,
                    longitude: 27.565993,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
            >
                <Icon name="menu" style={{ position: 'absolute', marginTop: 35, marginLeft: 15, fontSize: 50 }} onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ isMapVisible: false })
                    this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
                }} />
            </MapView>

        )
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `shouldComponentUpdate` to limit re-renders of the component? I'd also recommend using the performance profiling in the debugging tools to ensure you are targeting the exact function that is slowing down your UI thread.

Comment: Hi. I have been constantly searching for a solution and then tried the app on an adnroid emulator. It is smooth like butter so then i have searched more and found out that xCode emulator is not performing that well with react-native-maps.